# iTunes EPF missing data for movies

Tags: python, itunes

I'm using epfimporter.py provided by apple to import EPF relational for movies

However, I discovered that there's the following prices:
- sdPrice
- sdRentalPrice
- hdRentalPrice

It's consistently missing hdPrice. Is anyone else observing this data issue? Also I've observed there are some movie price info that are missing. E.g. id710862890 Don Jon it's already in the app store but I see no traces in EPF, either the full mode or incremental mode.

Not sure if it's because of the python script is problematic, or it's missing from the original data feed

Answer (score 0):

EPF archive isn't up today, sometime it has lug 1-4 days.
So I checked this id 710862890 and didn't find it in EPF tables artist, video_artist etc.

I advised you to create ticket in apple affiliate support site: http://itunesaffiliate.phgsupport.com/anonymous_requests/new (estimate answer time 2-3 days)

Comment: Thanks! So this is indeed a feed problem, though for 710862890 I haven't seen it in the feed for the past few months, even though the movie is available 2 months ago. Do you see the hdPrice field in the feed?